#  How does sound signature recognition work and how to override it?

Tags: legal, research, identification

Today a lot of websites that allow the upload of media content are implementing automatic sound signature checks to prevent the illegal distribution of videos containing copyrighted content.

- How does the sound recognition system work?
- How could such an algorithm be tricked?
- Could the sound be altered enough to change the sound signature without significantly changing the human experience of the sound?

Comment: Have you read http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/09/youtube-vs-fair-use.html?

Comment: Thanks, very good and informative article on the subject. It gives me a start point for investigation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recognition software is just comparing hashes/fingerprints...

see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_fingerprint  & 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function 
also might be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068286/music-recognition-and-signal-processing

and yes, you can get fake out many of those platforms (for whatever your perfectly legal purpose is) One possibility is detailed here: http://www.turkeymonkey.com/2009/07/19/how-to-get-around-that-pesky-copyrighted-audio-filter-on-youtube-and-facebook/